# SIGABRT signal after popping view in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am working on an iPhone application which is crashing after the routine tied to a button call is completed. I am popping the view which is at position index 1 on the navigation controller stack. The current view on which i clicked the button is on index 5.

The code I use for popping the view is as follows:

```
id callListController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
       if(nil != callListController)
       {
          [self.navigationController popToViewController:callListController animated:YES];
       }
```

I have tried setting break points in the above code and also in the code of the view to be loaded at index 1. Nothing works. Something is happening in between.

I used the crash report from the iphone (symbolicated) to analyze the issue. Honestly, I cannot make sense of symbolicated file. Here is the dump of main portion of the file since I could not attach with this questionnaire:

```
Incident Identifier: BDE0FFE7-D74F-46B5-A9BD-89AA4F483300
CrashReporter Key:   fbe272c09f9d46b3e962f897e0d8a5e3de9793e1
Hardware Model:      iPhone1,2
Process:         iwf [151]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F50D0AED-94A4-48A8-8B5D-0D88B2D4D36F/iwf.app/iwf
Identifier:      iwf
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-02-22 20:43:10.614 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0.1 (8A306)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00088c24 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00088c12 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00088c06 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0009f902 abort + 54
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008e6de szone_error + 230
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008e7ac free_tiny_botch + 60
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00001fe8 szone_free + 302
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00001ea0 malloc_zone_free + 64
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00053cc8 __CFAllocatorSystemDeallocate + 8
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000019d6 CFAllocatorDeallocate + 74
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000036c4 _CFRelease + 288
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00003566 CFRelease + 74
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00015898 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 124
13  Foundation                      0x00004822 -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 98
14  UIKit                           0x0007bc18 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7776
15  GraphicsServices                0x00004edc PurpleEventCallback + 1024
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000742ac __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 22
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000761d6 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0007718e __CFRunLoopRun + 574
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
21  GraphicsServices                0x00003f88 GSEventRunModal + 188
22  UIKit                           0x00007b40 -[UIApplication _run] + 564
23  UIKit                           0x00005fb8 UIApplicationMain + 964
24  iwf                             0x0000d434 main (main.m:14)
25  iwf                             0x0000d404 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00034e84 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00102a48 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00102494 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00102634 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b53c _pthread_wqthread + 392
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00082b6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000ab0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002f94 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00074b18 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000770e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   WebCore                         0x0000370c RunWebThread(void*) + 552
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008af80 _pthread_start + 364
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d014 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000ab0 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002f94 mach_msg + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00074b18 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000770e0 __CFRunLoopRun + 400
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0001e0bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001dfca CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
6   Foundation                      0x0003c316 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 210
7   Foundation                      0x0000c612 -[NSThread main] + 42
8   Foundation                      0x00092140 __NSThread__main__ + 908
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008af80 _pthread_start + 364
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d014 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00029f24 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0007aa54 __CFSocketManager + 340
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008af80 _pthread_start + 364
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007d014 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008c3b4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b718 _pthread_wqthread + 868
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00082b6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008c3b4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008b718 _pthread_wqthread + 868
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00082b6c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e73926c
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x067a9e50      r6: 0x0013f000      r7: 0x2fffe464
    r8: 0x05559084    r9: 0x00000888     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x0013f000
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffe464      lr: 0x3483fc19      pc: 0x3483fc24
  cpsr: 0x000f0010
```

I have a basic understanding that this error is happening when I shift views but I am little lost at this point.

Any advice will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Subbu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Izzy said, this is usually caused by releasing an autorelease object, a pretty common problem until you get a handle on memory management in Objective-C.

If you are not sure specifically where to look for the problem, you might want to start by commenting out all of the releases in viewWillDisappear/dealloc in your views, and assuming it works without crashing, start to put back in the releases until you narrow down an ivar that is causing a problem.  Most likely, you will find that the ivar is given an object that is an autorelease object, so you will either not release the object, retain the object, or use a method that gives you back a retained object.

Check this link for more background:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because you're over releasing in one of your view controllers.

P.S. You should check `viewControllers` length before asking for object with index 1. It can lead to crash if `viewControllers` array contains less than 2 objects.